# Bash selection menu based on command output

Tags: bash, shell

How can I make a selection menu based on other command output?
For example running following command:

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```

I am getting following output:

```
CURRENT   NAME         CLUSTER         AUTHINFO       NAMESPACE
*         Name1        Cluster1        Auth1        
          Name2        Cluster2        Auth3   
          Name3        Cluster3        Auth3
```

What I'd like to achieve is to print NAME and CLUSTER columns as a menu options and if any is selected pass it as variable to another command:

```
kubectl config use context $NameX
```

But have no idea how to do this with command output.

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: @anishsane Example of what? OP is not asking us to debug any code.

Comment: I meant, what is the expected output, expected input and what OP has tried/where OP is stuck.

Comment: @anishsane There is no input. The "output" is running `kubectl config use context` with the selected `Name` value. OP has tried nothing.

Comment: The most difficult part of the question is parsing a list of menu-entries from the output of the `kubectl` command. I'm not familiar with kubernetes but I believe that `kubectl`'s options might make that much easier : if you had a way to print only the names, then only the cluster names, you'd just have to concatenate those two results and feed them to `select` and you'd have your menu

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the output of a command as input to another one, you might use backticks or, more readable, `$()` (but the latter does not always work).

For example, give some more information on the `ls` "program":

```
which ls
file /bin/ls
```

This can be shortened to:

```
file $(which ls)
```

or:

```
file `which ls`
```

In your example, it will be something like:

```
kubectl config use context $(kubectl config get-contexts ...), or:
kubectl config use context `kubectl config get-contexts ...`
```

Obviously you'll need to specify exactly which information you need from the config in order for this to work.

Comment: When does `$()` not work? Only in some non-Bourne-derived shells and _very_ olds Bourne shells. Also, this doesn't answer the OP's question _in any way_.